# E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Tags: java, android, arrays, api

Here, i got some Error in my Adapter so my MainActivity is Getting error too, please help me.

This is my Log :

> I/om.azhar.myblo: ProcessProfilingInfo new_methods=1723 is saved saved_to_disk=1 resolve_classes_delay=8000
> W/om.azhar.myblo: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->setAlpnProtocols([B)V (light greylist, reflection)
> W/om.azhar.myblo: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->getAlpnSelectedProtocol()[B (light greylist, reflection)
> I/Choreographer: Skipped 84 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
> I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=1524ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=169077289183748, Vsync=169078689183692, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=169078696730293, AnimationStart=169078696978939, PerformTraversalsStart=169078696988835, DrawStart=169078713999512, SyncQueued=169078752086647, SyncStart=169078752488314, IssueDrawCommandsStart=169078752806804, SwapBuffers=169078812757116, FrameCompleted=169078814205293, DequeueBufferDuration=507000, QueueBufferDuration=536000,
> I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:169088627
> W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@ab1ed04
> E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
> I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=701ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=169088700935236, Vsync=169089184268550, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=169089199336435, AnimationStart=169089199481696, PerformTraversalsStart=169089202371018, DrawStart=169089396891487, SyncQueued=169089398607789, SyncStart=169089398712008, IssueDrawCommandsStart=169089398917268, SwapBuffers=169089400846643, FrameCompleted=169089402298935, DequeueBufferDuration=311000, QueueBufferDuration=499000,
> I/om.azhar.myblo: Compiler allocated 4MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
> W/Glide: Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an annotationProcessor compile dependency on com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler in your application and a @GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or LibraryGlideModules will be silently ignored
> D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.azhar.myblog, PID: 8439
> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
> at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
> at com.azhar.myblog.adapter.MainAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MainAdapter.java:60)
> at com.azhar.myblog.adapter.MainAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MainAdapter.java:28)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20710)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6198)
> at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1083)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20710)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6198)
> at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1083)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20710)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6198)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20710)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6198)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20710)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6198)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20710)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6198)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20710)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6198)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
> at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:757)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20710)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6198)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2871)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2398)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1534)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7420)
> at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1100)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:895)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:826)
> at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1086)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
> E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6861)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
> I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8439 SIG: 9

Here my Adapter :

```
package com.azhar.myblog.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.azhar.myblog.model.ModelMain;
import com.azhar.myblog.R;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.util.List;


public class MainAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<ModelMain> items;
    private MainAdapter.onSelectData onSelectData;
    private Context mContext;

    public interface onSelectData {
        void onSelected(ModelMain modelListLagu);
    }

    public MainAdapter(Context context, List<ModelMain> items, MainAdapter.onSelectData xSelectData) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.items = items;
        this.onSelectData = xSelectData;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_artikel, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final ModelMain data = items.get(position);

        //Get Image
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(data.getContent());
        Elements element = document.select("img");

        Glide.with(mContext)
//                .load(element.get(0).attr("src"))
                .load(element.get(0).attr("src"))
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .fitCenter()
                .into(holder.imgThumb);

        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(data.getAuthorImage())
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .fitCenter()
                .into(holder.imgAuthor);

        holder.tvTitle.setText(data.getTitle());
        holder.tvAuthor.setText(data.getAuthor());
        holder.tvDatePost.setText(data.getPublished());
        holder.rlArtikel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onSelectData.onSelected(data);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    //Class Holder
    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView tvTitle;
        public TextView tvAuthor;
        public TextView tvDatePost;
        public RelativeLayout rlArtikel;
        public ImageView imgThumb;
        public ImageView imgAuthor;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            rlArtikel = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rlArtikel);
            imgThumb = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgThumb);
            imgAuthor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgAuthor);
            tvTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            tvAuthor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAuthor);
            tvDatePost = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDatePost);
        }
    }

}
```

And here my MainActivity :

```
package com.azhar.myblog.activities

import android.app.ProgressDialog
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.androidnetworking.AndroidNetworking
import com.androidnetworking.common.Priority
import com.androidnetworking.error.ANError
import com.androidnetworking.interfaces.JSONObjectRequestListener
import com.azhar.myblog.R
import com.azhar.myblog.adapter.MainAdapter
import com.azhar.myblog.adapter.MainAdapter.onSelectData
import com.azhar.myblog.model.ModelMain
import com.azhar.myblog.networking.BloggerApi
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import org.json.JSONException
import org.json.JSONObject
import java.text.ParseException
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), onSelectData {

    var mainAdapter: MainAdapter? = null
    var mProgressBar: ProgressDialog? = null
    var modelMain: MutableList<ModelMain> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        mProgressBar = ProgressDialog(this)
        mProgressBar!!.setTitle("Mohon Tunggu")
        mProgressBar!!.setCancelable(false)
        mProgressBar!!.setMessage("Sedang menampilkan data...")

        llAbout.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, AboutActivity::class.java)) }

        llPP.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, PrivacyPolicyActivity::class.java)) }

        llDisclaimer.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, DisclaimerActivity::class.java)) }

//        fabSource.setOnClickListener {
//            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
//            intent.data = Uri.parse("https://github.com/AzharRivaldi")
//            startActivity(intent)
//        }

        rvListArticles.setHasFixedSize(true)
        rvListArticles.setLayoutManager(LinearLayoutManager(this))

        //get data
        listArticle
    }

    private val listArticle: Unit
        private get() {
            mProgressBar!!.show()
            AndroidNetworking.get(BloggerApi.ListPost)
                    .setPriority(Priority.MEDIUM)
                    .build()
                    .getAsJSONObject(object : JSONObjectRequestListener {
                        override fun onResponse(response: JSONObject) {
                            try {
                                mProgressBar!!.dismiss()
                                val playerArray = response.getJSONArray("items")
                                for (i in 0 until playerArray.length()) {
                                    val jsonObject1 = playerArray.getJSONObject(i)
                                    val dataApi = ModelMain()

                                    dataApi.title = jsonObject1.getString("title")
                                    dataApi.content = jsonObject1.getString("content")
                                    dataApi.labels = jsonObject1.getString("labels")
                                    dataApi.url = jsonObject1.getString("url")

                                    val datePost = jsonObject1.getString("published")
                                    val inputFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
                                    val outputFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")
                                    val date = inputFormat.parse(datePost)
                                    val datePostConvert = outputFormat.format(date)
                                    dataApi.published = datePostConvert

                                    val jsonObject2 = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("author")
                                    val authorPost = jsonObject2.getString("displayName")
                                    dataApi.author = authorPost

                                    val jsonObject3 = jsonObject2.getJSONObject("image")
                                    val authorImage = jsonObject3.getString("url")
                                    dataApi.authorImage = Uri.parse("http:$authorImage").toString()
                                    modelMain.add(dataApi)
                                    showListArticle()
                                }
                            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                                e.printStackTrace()
                                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,
                                        "Gagal menampilkan data!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            } catch (e: ParseException) {
                                e.printStackTrace()
                                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,
                                        "Gagal menampilkan data!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            }
                        }

                        override fun onError(anError: ANError) {
                            mProgressBar!!.dismiss()
                            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,
                                    "Tidak ada jaringan internet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                    })
        }

    private fun showListArticle() {
        mainAdapter = MainAdapter(this@MainActivity, modelMain, this)
        rvListArticles!!.adapter = mainAdapter
    }

    override fun onSelected(modelMain: ModelMain) {
        val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, DetailArtikelActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("detailArtikel", modelMain)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks that the `element.get(0)` is the problem. I assume not all items in your adapter contains the img property. You should check if the img exists before getting it.